# regex get first number from dotted number seris

Tags: python, regex

My input is dotted numbers like these

```
1.10.12.111
x22.34.11.827.11234
>345.123.11.23885.101010
```

so, simply my input pattern is

```
any alphanumeric value . any number . any number . .... ...... ....
```

I want to get first value before first dot. I have tried this way

```
import re
number = '>345.123.11.23885.101010'
pat = re.compile(r'(\d*)\..+')
match = re.search(pat,number)
print match.group(1) // 23885 as result
```

Comment: What went wrong ?

Comment: You can catch the first number before dot like this. `\D*(\d+)\..*`

Comment: Your code returns `345` - see https://ideone.com/8Gb1Q0

Comment: Yes @WiktorStribiżew you are correct. I misunderstood

Comment: Before resorting to the power saw (regex) don't forget about the scissors (split): `parts = number.split('.')`. Maybe that will allow you to get the item you need?

Answer (score 1):

Use line delimiters.

```
import re
number = '>345.123.11.23885.101010'
pat = re.compile(r'^\D*(\d+)')
match = re.search(pat,number)
print match.group(1)
```

- **^** means line start
- **\D*** Not a digit 0+ times

Comment: Write the output as well. It makes sure that the code is tested.

Comment: What do you mean by *line delimiters*? The `^` anchor? It matches the start of a string in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
number = '>345.123.11.23885.101010'
l = number.split('.',1)[0][-1]
```

out:

```
'5'
```

first we split str by '.', and get first part, than get the first's last number